# What documents are required for a Thai citizen to travel from Thailand to Indonesia?

Tags: paperwork, indonesia, thai-citizens

I'm interested in traveling abroad but I have never been abroad before. I live in Thailand and I want to go to Indonesia. Can you suggest me about the document and what I have to prepare for traveling to Indonesia?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is *way too broad*. You need a passport for almost b but not all international travel but the rest really depends on too many things.

Comment: User84439, can you state 1) where you live, 2) your nationality, and 3) your destination (country?). The answer varies substantially based on these. For example, French people living in Spain can visit Belgium with only their ID card. But pretty much everybody needs a passport *and a visa* to enter India, for instance.

Comment: Can you show us what you have already found? We do not give answers to the most basic of questions because so much is already written. But we are happy to help you when you get stuck in your research.

Comment: I live in Thailand and my nationality is Thai. Actually, I want to go to many countries but I think  Indonesia is my first destination. Now I have found that I don't need to have a VISA for traveling to Indonesia. Can you suggest me more about other document or what I have to prepare?

Comment: As a Thai citizen, you don't need a visa (note, the word visa is normally spelled in small letters) to stay in Indonesia for up to 30 days (the day of arrival and the day of departure both included). In most cases, all you need is just a passport. However, Indonesian passport control officers may ask for return (or onward) ticket and hotel booking(s), so it is wise to have them printed and at hand. Also it is recommended to have a travel insurance policy, so that, if you get sick while in Indonesia, medical expenses wouldn't hurt you financially too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a passport valid for at least 6 months from the date you enter Indonesia

You can then stay for 30 days without further permits.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to include some words about whether additional evidence will be needed (proof of funds or accommodation, for example).